# Can the SQL JOIN 'USING()' clause be used with one or more 'AND ON()' clauses for a single join..?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

In a DB2-400 SQL join, can the `USING()` clause be used with one or more AND ON clauses for a single join..? This is for a situation where *some* field names are the same, but *not all*, so USING() would only apply to *part* of the join.

I could have sworn I've done this before and it worked, but now it eludes me.

I've tried various combinations as shown below, but none of them work. Perhaps I'm simply mistaken and it's not possible:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 USING (COL1,COL2) AND ON (T1.COL3=T2.COL4)

SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON (T1.COL3=T2.COL4) AND USING (COL1,COL2)

SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON (T1.COL3=T2.COL4), USING (COL1,COL2)

SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 USING (COL1,COL2,(1.COL3=T2.COL4))
```

Comment: I think `on (t1.col1, t1.col2) = (t2.col1, t2.col2) and t1.col3 = t2.col4` is probably the shortest way to write it - but I don't know if DB2 supports that. http://rextester.com/LOCT2135

Comment: Weird syntax... To keep USING(), I'd put the other _inner_ join conditions in the WHERE clause. (But I'd rather switch to regular ON syntax.)

Comment: Yea, I'm working in DBeaver (a client like DBSquirrel) connected to DB2, and I haven't been able to get it to work, keep getting `SQL0199`. This is for a complicated query with three physical tables, and two  "unpivots" as joined `UNION` subqueries, each with half a dozen subselects. And one of the `ON` clauses is a `BETWEEN`, so the join pulls in a range of records rather than a perfect A=B, lol. Just trying to make this mess more readable if possible. I've cleaned it up a lot, but it still needs work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the syntax diagram here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzjoinedt.htm

I suggest that the only options for `JOIN USING` are a comma separated list of columns

```
JOIN table-reference USING ( column-name [, column-name] ... )
```

and you can't mix `USING` with `ON`

Comment: Yes, it's looking like that's the answer. As I mentioned in my OP, I thought I've done this before and it worked, but it seems I'm mistaken and it does not work.

Comment: @spinjector FYI you also can't `from tbl1 join tbl2 using(colA) join tbl3 using (colA)` in Db2 for IBM i...

Comment: Not sure I understand that. You mean you can't have multiple `inner join` clauses after the `from`, or you can't have two `using` clauses with the same column name for different joins..?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `where`:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 INNER JOIN
     T2 USING (COL1, COL2) 
WHERE T1.COL3 = T2.COL4;
```

Another alternative would be to use a subquery to rename the column in one of the tables.